# Can't reset my gametime to zero in XNA

Tags: xna-4.0

I'm creating a game with XNA 4.0 and I have a problem with resetting the game time in my game,

the problem is I'm using this code for adding my objects in game:

```
Timespan prevSpawn = timespan.zero;
Timespan objectSpawnTime = timespan.fromsec(5);

if (gameTime.TotalGameTime - prevSpawn> objectSpawnTime)
        {
            prevSpawn = gameTime.TotalGameTime;
            AddObject();
        }
```

I want to reset the game time to zero, when start the game again or game end and goes to mainmenu and hit the play again, I want to reset gametime.

Comment: is your issue not getting into your above if statement or is it with how to reset the actual game time. Do you have events ready for each of the actions you mention above?

Comment: the issue is reseting actual game time to zero,when my game end its going to state which i called tryAgain state and there is a button i used to replay the game the name of button is "play again" , so when i push this button the game start working fine but the problem is i cant make the gametime.totalgametime to zero , i dunno if there another way of coding to make objects respawn every 5 sec

Answer (score 2):

As i understand from the MSDN entry below, the GameTime.TotalGameTime property will continue 'ticking' until you end the game, or, entire application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime.totalgametime.aspx

Perhaps it would be wiser to use your own object, for which you can reset with any of your actions and hence have more control over the time span. Then you could still use this property for counting the difference from one and the other.

i.e. when you reset/restart etc, do not refer to TotalGameTime and try to make it be zero, but refer to your own object's timespan, or to (TotalGameTime - TimeWhenReset) where TimeWhenReset is the timespan copied from TotalGameTime when you reset.

This is untested, but I think that it should work if I understood correctly.

Comment: This is, indeed, the way to do this kind of thing. gameTime refers to the whole application and you can use a class with static fields to manage the internal game time. No need to test.

Answer (score 0):

For a more accurate timer, you would be better using a time span, and a DateTime vairable. Set the DateTime to now when you want to start the timer, and in the TimeSpan do something like this:

```
timer = StartTime - DateTime.Now;
```

This will give you a timer you can deploy at any time.